# how to pass a variable number in the URL with vue.js/express

Tags: javascript, html, express, vue.js

So as the title says I am using vue.js and express to make my website. What I would like to happen is: when a certain button is pressed on a page, the user is sent to a new page and a variable value is appended to the url so that on the new page I can call my database on load and populate the page.
At the moment I have a function on my new page that runs on load and with an ID it can populate all the information I need in the page.

**So I have two main questions:**

1. How do I send the user to the new page if the url does not match the new page's directory? For example, if the url of my new page is `/Matchpage.html` how do I make it so that `/1/Matchpage.html` actually points to the same html page?
2. My second question is once I managed to do step 1 how do I fetch that value from the URL using vue.js or express?

Comment: You can actually try doing this by passing query params and reading them via javascript or jquery.